# How to change variable value according to a disired pattern in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm sorry the question might be a little weird but I don't know how to ask this otherwise.

I have been developing an endless runner game, and downloaded this great [asset package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/55306) from store. It will bend the road or tiles left or right according to the desired amount.

I have a set of numbers in my mind -10, 0 and 10,

10 will bend the tiles to the left. (according to the asset, (+) is left.)

0 will do nothing, it will be straight tiles.

-10 will bend the tiles to the right

Right now I have developed it to gradually increase the curve to the left and stop at 10.

This is the code.

```
float curve = 0;
float curTarget = 10;

void Update () 
    {
 if (curve <= curTarget)
        {
            curve = curve + (Time.deltaTime * .5f);
        }
        else if (curve == curTarget)
        {
            HB.ApplyCurvature(curve); //method called from the package.
        }
        HB.ApplyCurvature(curve); //method called from the package
}
```

So my question is how to increase and decrease those values between each other (-10, 0, 10). Basically I want the pattern to be;

decrease gradually from 0 to -10 waitForSeconds(5)

Increase gradually from -10 to 0 waitForSeconds(5)

Increase gradually from 0 to 10 waitForSeconds(5)

Finally then decrease from 10 to 0 waitForSeconds(5) and then from top again.

How do I achieve such a scenario, I tried to use a switch but it didn't work out.
This is also same as the subway surfers. It beautifully go through with this pattern. I'm bit new to unity. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As new Unity progammer, it is important that you understand how to use `coroutine` and the `lerp` function. This is one example where it is needed. How to move object over time... This has been asked many times, so Googling them should yield a great result and get you started. You must know those in order to do this.

```
bool keepRunning = false;
IEnumerator pattern()
{
    while (keepRunning)
    {
        float mainPatternValue = 0;

        //decrease gradually from 0 to -10 waitForSeconds(5)
        const float patternDuration = 5f;
        float counter = 0;
        while (counter < patternDuration)
        {
            if (!keepRunning)
                yield break;

            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            mainPatternValue = Mathf.Lerp(0, -10, counter / patternDuration);
            Debug.Log("<color=red>Decr from 0 to -10: " + mainPatternValue + "</color>");
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("<color=yellow>DONE</color>");

        //Increase gradually from -10 to 0 waitForSeconds(5)
        counter = 0;
        mainPatternValue = -10;
        while (counter < patternDuration)
        {
            if (!keepRunning)
                yield break;

            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            mainPatternValue = Mathf.Lerp(-10, 0, counter / patternDuration);
            Debug.Log("<color=green>Incr from -10 to 0: " + mainPatternValue + "</color>");
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("<color=yellow>DONE</color>");

        //Increase gradually from 0 to 10 waitForSeconds(5)
        counter = 0;
        mainPatternValue = 0;
        while (counter < patternDuration)
        {
            if (!keepRunning)
                yield break;

            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            mainPatternValue = Mathf.Lerp(0, 10, counter / patternDuration);
            Debug.Log("<color=red>Incr from 0 to 10: " + mainPatternValue + "</color>");
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("<color=yellow>DONE</color>");

        //Finally then decrease from 10 to 0 waitForSeconds(5) and then from top again
        counter = 0;
        mainPatternValue = 10;
        while (counter < patternDuration)
        {
            if (!keepRunning)
                yield break;

            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            mainPatternValue = Mathf.Lerp(10, 0, counter / patternDuration);
            Debug.Log("<color=green>Decr from 10 to 0: " + mainPatternValue + "</color>");
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("<color=yellow>Finally DONE</color>");
        Debug.Log("<color=yellow>Starting Over Again!</color>");
        yield return null;
    }
}

void start()
{
    if (keepRunning)
        return;

    keepRunning = true;
    StartCoroutine(pattern());
}

void stop()
{
    keepRunning = false;
}
```

To start the `coroutine` call `start()`. To stop it call `stop()`.

Comment: The answer worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for helping out. Also both answers help me very much and I learned new things. Thank you. Since I can'y accept both questions, I voted up both of them and accepted the answer that I used. :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm on mobile so I can't test it but hopefully this helps...

Use this function to return a value to increment/decrement the current curvature by based on the difference between the target curve and the current curve.

It currently uses just Time.deltaTime as the increment. I added in a commented out curve speed apply line, just remove the /* and */ and give curveSpeed a value to make use of it.

```
 float Bend(float current, float target) {
    //Don't bend if current curve is equal to target curve
    if (current == target)
        return 0;
    //Find the sign of the difference between current and target
    float sgn = (target - current) / Math.Abs(target - current);
    //Apply the sign to the incremental value
    float val = /*curveSpeed * */Time.deltaTime * sgn;
    //If the absolute value of the increment/decrement + the current value is greater than 
    //the absolute value of the target, only return the difference (prevents over curving)
    if (Mathf.Abs(current + val) > Mathf.Abs(target)) {
        return target-current;
    }
    //Return the incremental/decremental value
    return val;
}
```

So an example of implementing this in a pattern within update:

```
enum Pattern { a, b, c, d }
Pattern pattern;

float curve = 0;
float curveSpeed = 2; 

void Update() {
    switch (pattern) {
        case Pattern.a:
            HB.ApplyCurvature(Bend(curve, -10));
            if (Bend(curve, -10) == 0) pattern = Pattern.b;
            break;

        case Pattern.b:
            HB.ApplyCurvature(Bend(curve, 0));
            if (Bend(curve, 0) == 0) pattern = Pattern.c;
            break;

        case Pattern.c:
            HB.ApplyCurvature(Bend(curve, 10));
            if (Bend(curve, 10) == 0) pattern = Pattern.d;
            break;

        case Pattern.d:
            HB.ApplyCurvature(Bend(curve, 0));
            if (Bend(curve, 0) == 0) pattern = Pattern.a;
            break;

    }
}
```

The only thing missing is the delay you mentioned.

Comment: yes I can add the delay using `yield return new WaitforSeconds(5)`. Hope it helps for everyone else.